# Keep bokeh widgets running in app

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

## What I do want to do

make a kind of dashboard server for my working group where one can choose which dashboard he wants. The dashboard consists on plots and widgets that often cannot be handled by js but by python callback function.

## What is working

- a bokeh server and a flat server
- Dashboard are running fine on a bokeh server.
- I have a running Flask server and I am able to show the user selected dahshboard. The dashboard are rooted kind of this way:

  ```
  from bokeh.embed import autoload_server,  Document
  from flask import Flask, render_template

  config = {}
  app = Flask(__name__)

  app.root("/focusmap")
  def serve_focusmap():
      dashboard = get_focusmap_dashboard() # a bokeh plot and widget layout        
      document = Document()
      document.add_root(dashboard)   
      document.title = name

      session = push_session(document, session_id=None)
      body = autoload_server(None, session_id=session.id) 
      config['currentSession'] = session
      return render_template("board.html", body=body)
  ```

  This works fine to show the dashboard but widgets does not work because a `session.loop_until_closed()` is missing somewhere.

Reading the bokeh server doc I red that the `loop_until_closed` is not handled by the bokeh server but from the app.

## What is not working

I cannot figure out how to make the `session.loop_until_closed()` without blocking the app.

I have tried :

```
@app.after_request
def loopSession(response):
    global config
    session  = config.get('currentSession',None)
    if session:
        session.loop_until_closed()
return response
```

But of course it is blocking the app.

Does anybody have experience with it ? Should I / can I run the loop_until_closed in a subprocess ?

Answer (score 1):

The `loop_until_closed` function is always blocking.

*UPDATE: `loop_until_closed` is being removed from public API in Bokeh 2.0*

Your only option would be to run that function in a thread but doing that for every connection could be unwieldy. That section also states that if you want to scale out an app (i.e. deploy it more than locally), that using `bokeh.client` is really not the appropriate tool:

> **If you need to scale out a Bokeh application, running them directly on a Bokeh server is preferable.**

Running directly on a bokeh server means e.g making an `app.py` that you run with

```
bokeh serve app.py
```

As described in this section:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#building-bokeh-applications

Then this app can be embedding in a Flask app using `autoload_server`, or IFrames.

Otherwise, you can also now start a Bokeh server as a "library" by running the server explicitly on an `IOLoop` that you create and control. This means you can run an Bokeh server "inside" a Flask app. Examples (including a Flask one) are linked from here:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library

Comment: Okay. Something that was missing in the puzzle, and not easy to find, was how to access to the http request to make the bokeh app case dependent on order to show the user board:  app?board=focusmap for instance. Now that I have this ( http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#accessing-the-http-request ) I can embed the app in a iframe with the right src

Comment: FWIW that is described here http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#accessing-the-http-request If there is somewhere else, or something that could improve it, please let us know on GitHub. Also FYI in `0.12.4` there is a bug with query parameter and `--num-threads` greater than 1. That issue is fixed in master and in the latest dev builds (and will be in `0.12.5` in a few weeks)

Comment: Also please note that starting in `0.12.5` the `request.arguments` (i.e. the query parameters) is the *only* part of the request that is available.